# Laptop keyboard doesn't work after installing vista driver on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-vista, keyboard

I just accidentally installed a vista driver for a touchpen tablet on the lenovo computer of my mum which runs windows 7. After rebooting, her keyboard wouldn't work any more. I personally doubt that the driver is the reason. I got it from www.softpedia.com and googled if this website ever had a virus online and didn't find anything. I also didn't have to enter a password for the installation process which you normally have to do when installing something that could really affect your computer negatively. If i enter the system control and klick on "keyboard" it says that the keyboard works flawless. Could the driver be the problem? If not, what could be causing the problem? Is there any way to uninstall a driver without a keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Strange one...

You can uninstall a driver without the keyboard. If you are now in Windows 7, open Start menu, right-click in "Computer" -> Properties. Go to devices administrator, search your keyboard, and uninstall it.